# Removing NaN or replacing NaN by $0$

Tags: self-study, survival, biostatistics, kaplan-meier

Suppose $\delta_i$ is a censoring indicator, $w_i$ is weight, and $\hat S(t_i)$ is Kaplan-Meier estimate.  A part of an equation is $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\delta_i\times w_i}{\hat S(t_i)}$. For some  $i$, $\hat S(t_i)$ is zero. In that case $\frac{\delta_i\times w_i}{\hat S(t_i)}$ equals NaN.

Should I remove those subjects for whom $\hat S(t_i)$ is equal to zero?

For example, if I have 10 subjects and for 2 of them $\hat S(t_i)=0$, then should I consider $n=8$ in $$n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\delta_i\times w_i}{\hat S(t_i)}$$
? Or, do I need to replace the NaN by $0$ and keep $n=10$?

Comment: Censored data is unobservable. 0 is a realized value. The two are not compatible. You can either use MLE without full data, or try something like EM (or MCEM) to calculated an adjusted MLE estimate

Comment: @Jon Do I need to substitute the kaplan-meier estimate by adjusted MLE estimate. I am not understanding. Could you  give me reference?

Comment: I can't say. I have experience in using EM (expectation-maximazation) for parameter estimation, however, very little experience with survival analysis. But, if you can specify your likelihood, then log-likelihood, you should be able to find a conditional MLE for your parameter estimate. Then, you can iterate through conditional values till your MLE estimates converge.

Comment: I may have not explained it well, but if you can specify your likelihood (or log-likelihood) I can take a look sometime while I'm at work..